# PHP issue after getting fragment from url.

Tags: php, javascript, hash, fragment

I have some page, it's url is like `http://www.domainname.com/m1.php?#m2.php?more=apple&starting=1`.

I want get the value `$_GET['more']` & `$_GET['starting']`.

I use this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parts = location.href.split('#');
if(parts.length > 1)
{
    var params = parts[0].split('?');
    var mark = '?';
    if(params.length > 1)
    {
        mark = '&';
    }
    location.href = parts[0] + mark + 'fragment=' + parts[1] ;
}
</script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['fragment']))
{
    echo $_GET['fragment'];
}
?>
```

but I still get the `m2.php?more=apple` and lost `starting=1`. How to get 2 of them? and then divide into `$_GET['more']` & `$_GET['starting']`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code really isn't even close to getting those two values.  I'm not sure what to make of it since it is so far off.

If your PHP code is running *after* setting the new location, then you will want the values `more` and `starting` to be *before* the hash (`#`) as the hash part does not get sent to the server.

If you want to get the `more` and `starting` values in JavaScript, then it can be either place, but you need to know what stage you are at to get it the right way.

#### Examples

URL: **http://www.domainname.com/m2.php?more=apple&starting=1**

Query string: `more=apple&starting=1`
Hash: *none*

```
<?php
echo $_GET['more']; // apple
echo $_GET['starting']; // 1
```

---

URL: **http://www.domainname.com/m1.php?#m2.php?more=apple&starting=1**

Query string: *none*
Hash: `m2.php?more=apple&starting=1`

```
<?php
echo count($_GET) // 0
```

Javascript:

```
var hash = location.hash; // m2.php?more=apple&starting=1
var hashparts = hash.split("?");
var urlhashpart = hashparts[0]; // m2.php
var querystringhashpart = hashparts[1]; // more=apple&starting=1
var params = querystringhashpart.split("&");
for (var i in params) {
    var param = params[i].split("=");
    document.write(param[0] + ": " + param[1]); // outputs 'more: apple', 'starting: 1'
}
```

Comment: I added your last `Javascript`, but there is no alart pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're looking to get this information for use in PHP, a simple combination of `parse_url()` and `parse_str()` will also do the trick:

```
$url = parse_url('http://www.domainname.com/m1.php?#m2.php?more=apple&starting=1');
$anchorparts = explode('?',$url['fragment']);
parse_str($anchorparts[1],$vars);
```

A dump of `$vars` then yields:

```
array(2) {
  ["more"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["starting"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```